# How to pass Array/Values to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, scope

I am learning Javascript for a project using online resources however i don't know how to get this function working.

```
var results =[[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]];
var winner = 0;

function checkWinner (results)
{ 
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    if (results[0][i] > 50)
    {
      winner = results[0][i];

    }
}
```

Just after the function, i use:
    checkWinner(results);

In a HTML file i use alert to display the variable winner. But it obviously doesn't work. I realise it is a problem with my understanding of scope and global variables.

Comment: Post all of the javascript code.

Comment: can you show us place where are you calling this ?

Comment: How are you calling the function, and where are you printing the value of winner?

Comment: We don't know the values in `aX` variables. That might help.

Comment: Also, any particular reason why you'd use `[[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]]` instead of just `[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]`?

Comment: I have edit the question to show how i am calling the function. I use a the alert tag in another HTML file to display the value winner.

Answer (score 3):

should be

```
var Results =[[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]];
var winner = 0;

function checkWinner (results)
{ 
  for (var i = 0; i < results[0].length; i++)
    if (results[0][i] > 50)
    {
      winner = results[0][i];

    }
}

checkWinner(Results);
```

To avoid name collisions name global variables from capital case.
Also in your code you call the length of the "parent" array. You need to specify the length of the "Child" array

Comment: If you are using the global `winner`, why not just remove `results` from the argument list as well?

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the `result[0]` array (the array in `result[0]`), but using the length of the `result` array.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to understand the concept of [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope). The variables `results` and `winner` are not the same inside and outside the function.

Also, you've got to *call* the function and *return* something from it if you want to change the value of the variables outside the function (unless you use globals). This seems to be hard for novice programmers to understand, but merely defining a function doesn't do anything.

```
var results =[[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]];

function checkWinner (results)
{ 
    for (var result in results[0]) 
    {
        if (result > 50)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}

var winner = checkWinner(results);
```

Note that:

- I used a for each loop, which has a cleaner syntax.
- I am also iterating over `results[0]` instead of `results`, since you've got a nested array for whatever reason.
- Because your function has an argument called `results`, it requires you to pass the global `results` in spite of it being a global. Another way to do this:

---

```
var results = [[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]];

function checkWinner()
{ 
    for (var result in results[0]) 
    {
        if (result > 50)
        {
            winner = result;
            return;
        }
    }
}

checkWinner();
```

However, I would recommend against using global variables this way. Here's an explanation on why [global variables are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad). It's for C++, but it applies to JavaScript as well.

Comment: Scoping the variables is the question of the functionality. For example if you are using knockout.js then it is useful to have a `viewModel` as a global variable. Local variables as parameters are useful for reusability. In general it's the decision of the devloper wich to apply.

Comment: Thanks for that. I used an edited version of your code you provided there thank you. I have always had problem understanding scope and variables in Javascript. However i'm getting there. Progress has been made!